# jQuery Autocomplete delete characters if nothing is returned

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using jQuery UI autocomplete to populate a text input remotely in a form. I have the information all flowing ok and returning properly but would like to do a couple of things to better enhance the ui instead of validating the input post fill. Currently it's being written in PHP dynamically and then utilized in the front. so...

```
$js .= "$( function(){";
$js .= "$('#" . $config->settings['field_name'] . "_" . $suggestiveFieldArray . "').autocomplete({";
$js .= "source: function( request, response ){";
$js .= "$.ajax({";
$js .= "url: '" . $thisURL . "',";
$js .= "dataType: 'jsonp',";
$js .= "data: {";
$js .= "term: request.term,";
$js .= "dependents: '". $thisVAR . "',";
$js .= "field: '". $config->settings['field_name'] . "_" . $suggestiveFieldArray . "',";
$js .= "fieldSettings: " . json_encode($fieldSettings);
$js .= "},";
$js .= "success: function( data ) {";
$js .= "response( data );";
$js .= "},";
$js .= "minLength: 0";
$js .= "});";
$js .= "}";
$js .= "});";
$js .= "});";
```

Would be:

```
$( function(){
    $('#" . $config->settings['field_name'] . "_" . $suggestiveFieldArray . "').autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ){
            $.ajax({
                url: '" . $thisURL . "',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: {
                    term: request.term,
                    dependents: '". $thisVAR . "',
                    field: '". $config->settings['field_name'] . "_" . $suggestiveFieldArray . "',
                    fieldSettings: " . json_encode($fieldSettings)
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( data );
                },
                minLength: 0";
            });
        }
    });
});
```

On the back end I am (in short) returning the following:

```
array( "id" => $row['name'] . '-' . $row['code'], "label" => $row['name'], "value" => $row['name'] );
```

The thing I would like to do is trigger a hidden error message field in the label of the input field and delete the key just triggered thus not allowing them to type in invalid data and let them know why.

The returning data I am providing is being validated on the back end already. So if no suggestions are provided then there is nothing valid to input.

I have tried various things to check the data and played with some of the methods and events in the [jQuery UI API](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), but so far have fallen short.

Is there a method to call or an event to catch on return where I could check the info in data? And if so, how would I go about deleting the keyed data?

*** EDIT ***

per @miknik request...

When 'E' typed into field and there are locations available vs. when they are NOT available.

Valid Data = (via console XHR Preview)

```
jQuery213038349144725773976_1512237603485([{id: "Eakly-OK", label: "Eakly", value: "Eakly"}, {id: "Edmond-OK", label: "Edmond", value: "Edmond"},…]);
0:{id: "Eakly-OK", label: "Eakly", value: "Eakly"}
1:{id: "Edmond-OK", label: "Edmond", value: "Edmond"}
2:{id: "El Reno-OK", label: "El Reno", value: "El Reno"}
3:{id: "Elk City-OK", label: "Elk City", value: "Elk City"}
4:{id: "Enid-OK", label: "Enid", value: "Enid"}
5:{id: "Eufaula-OK", label: "Eufaula", value: "Eufaula"}
```

Invalid Data:

```
jQuery2130021538268901126534_1512237746135([]);
No properties
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what data is valid and what is invalid?

Comment: Ah OK, I think I get it. If your autocomplete returns no results you want to throw an error and reset input field?

Comment: Yes... Not so much 'reset' the field though. Just delete the last character typed (which returned the invalid option).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a global variable to hold the last input to your text box, I'll call it `goodText`.

Either bind a keydown event handler to the textbox to set the value of the variable or set it as part of the success function of your ajax call.

Modify your success function to check the data response and have an if/else condition based on the number of responses returned

```
if (!data || !Object.keys(data).length)
```

If its empty, insert code to display whatever error message you want, and then revert the value of your textbox to that last good value:

```
$('#textInput').val(goodText);
```

Else, do whatever you do when they get a good response, add code to set `goodText` here if you want to update it that way.

You might want to delay the autocomplete until they have entered a couple of characters